# When async block concurrency is more than one, what happens when exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I have a DataFlow with a TransformBlock that runs an async disk Read method concurrently.  For example, reading several files from disk array that provides performance benefits with a non-single read request queue depth.

Intuitively, all pipeline work should have finished when the last ActionBlock completes.  However, the following happens:

Let's say Rabbit and Bear begin fetching two files into their own byte buffers.  Rabbit throws an EatenByAWolf exception.  Bear completes later, since its file is a bit larger.  By the time Bear comes awake from winter-long hibernation, EatenByAWolf exception seems to have propagated to Completion wait-site of the last ActionBlock.  Well, the problem is that here I clean up byte buffers for Rabbit and Bear alike, causing Bear to choke on an NullRefToBuffer exception.

What is the recommended approach?  Should I also wait for Reader block (containing all animals) to finish before clearing buffers, or could this be handled more elegantly?

```
Task.WaitAll(new[] { readerBlock.Completion, lastActionBlock.Completion });
```

versus

```
lastActionBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was managing byte buffers at a wrong level of abstraction.

The solution for me was to use a stateful reader object when creating TransformBlock that performs multiple async reads.  Adding `ConcurrentBag<>` of buffers to the `MyFileReaderWithCachingByteBuffers` reader object ensures that buffers won't clean up until the reader object captured by closure goes out of scope.  That happens only when all read operations complete.

```
var fileReader = new MyFileReaderWithCachingByteBuffers(biggestFileSize);
var readerBlock = new TransformBlock<string, MyObject>(
           animal => fileReader.ReadAsync(animal),
           new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = customDOP });
```